# Unable to reference HTML values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a Django app and need to do some Javascript processing in the HTML Template. In order to pass values from Django's templating language into Javascript, I have saved the values into meta tags as below:

```
<head>
    {% for candidate in candidates %}
        <meta id="cand" data-id="{{candidate.id}}" data-order="{{forloop.counter}}">
        <h3>{{forloop.counter}}</h3>
    {% endfor %}
</head>
```

I then try to access the data here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var metatags = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
for (var i = 0; i < metatags.length; i++) {
    console.log(metatags[i].data-id)
}

</script>
```

However, an issue is thrown trying to access the data:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined
```

In reference to the line `console.log(metatags[i].data-id)`

Why is this not working, am I attempting something impossible, and is there a better or more elegant way of accessing template values in Javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ids have to be unique, `<h3>` is not a valid child of `<head>`

Comment: Try to use the dataset property of the element to access your id like so: `metatags[i].dataset.id`

Comment: `data-id` is not a valid js identifier, it is parsed as `data - id` (variable "data" minus variable "id").

Comment: and thsi has absolutely nothing to do with django FWIW (removed tags).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have incorrect syntax for accessing HTML attributes using JavaScript.

Two ways to access data attributes,

1. Using `dataset`

   `console.log(metatags[i].dataset.id)`

   Learn more about [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)
2. Using `getAttribute`

   `console.log(metatags[i].getAttribute('data-id'))`

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the property like this:

```
 console.log(metatags[i].getAttribute("data-id"));
```